# ZF2 find available services provided by framework

Tags: zend-framework2

is there a list of available services provided by the framework anywhere?
Perhaps something like one or a few central config file(s) somewhere?

What is the easiest way to obtain such a list?

I know it's possible to parse the global merged configuration programmatically, e.g. in a module's Module.php listening to the onBootstrap event.
If that is the only way, then is there maybe already a publicly available module or piece of code to do so?

Reason: I want to browse them in order to see what I could use. It's not related to a specific problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All services which provided by default are documented here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.services.html#default-services

Answer (score 2):

The **Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager** class has a function called **getRegisteredServices**. This is the code, you'll get the idea of what it retrieves:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a keyed list of all registered services. Handy for debugging!
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getRegisteredServices()
{
    return array(
        'invokableClasses' => array_keys($this->invokableClasses),
        'factories' => array_keys($this->factories),
        'aliases' => array_keys($this->aliases),
        'instances' => array_keys($this->instances),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the #2 solution I was looking for. Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the merged config, you will not get all the services.

Maybe you can try to dump `ServiceManager::getRegisteredServices`

[Documentation here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.ServiceManager.ServiceManager.html#getRegisteredServices)